# If the sum converges to zero, does that mean that each sequence converges to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

If we are given that the sequence sum of two sequences of positive real numbers converges to zero, does that mean that each sequence converges to zero? (by the squeeze theorem)

Comment: For sum reason this question was very hard to parse

Comment: How can the sum of a sequence of positive numbers converge to zero?

Answer (score 6):

Let $x_n$ and $y_n$ be your sequences.

The answer is yes since
$$
0\leq x_n\leq x_n+y_n\quad\mbox{and}\quad 0\leq y_n\leq x_n+y_n
$$
and then you can apply the squeeze theorem.

Comment: What's going on today? Why the downvote?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @anon271828 Thanks! But that's just the very beginning of a reasoning.

Answer (score 4):

If the sequence $a_n+b_n$ converges to zero and $a_n, b_n$ are positive then $a_n$ (and by symmetry $b_n$) converges to zero because it's bounded below by 0 and above by some sequence that tends towards zero.